# What exactly is a "non-fungible token" and why would anyone care or want one?

Tags: fungibility

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-fungible_token

I've read that many times. It makes zero sense to me. (Just like 99,99% of the nonsensical word salad that's said these days.)

Okay, so it's some kind of garbagecoin where each coin is "unique", and that's somehow... worth money? What?

Isn't the truth that this is just yet another crypto currency-related scam designed purely to make people give them money so that they can buy more Bitcoin, the only crypto-currency which has actual value?

Answer (score 2):

[image: NFT-Lightnite]

**What is NFT?**

Non-Fungible Token. Tokens that are unique and used for something special.

*Is it something new and useful?*

No its not a new concept IMO. Can be useful in some cases and off-chain tokens used in games like Lightnite for skins makes sense. They are trending for now and there will be lot of people trying to make money from such online trends. Some will lose money.

NFTs using bitcoin tech:

LN: https://scarce.city/

[Liquid](https://medium.com/blockstream/native-confidential-assets-on-the-liquid-network-293091b3c4c6): https://explorer.lightnite.io/

[Rootstock](https://developers.rsk.co/tutorials/tokens/create-a-collectable-token/): https://watafan.com/#/marketplace

LNP/BP: https://github.com/LNP-BP/LNPBPs/blob/647acb854783b3caa9a84f782d199c19e64d9e28/lnpbp-0021.md

You can also sell digital content without NFTs: https://github.com/yzernik/squeaknode